# Can I Turn a Certain Version of Dolphin Emulator That Is Not Compatible With Ubuntu Into Something Usable on Dolphin?

Tags: 14.04, emulation

I would like to play this https://dolphin-emu.org/download/dev/c5b1ec3329d47006bfddb381f730ad4310528b00/ version of Dolphin Emulator on my Ubuntu Chromebook but the only problem is there is no Linux compatible version. Whenever I use the `sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu` command, it gives me the newest version which is not compatible with the online capabilities this specific version has. I know some people have got it to work for them on Linux, but all of their guides never work for me. Is there any way to make it compatible with Ubuntu (14.04) and if so, how? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> which is not compatible with the online capabilities this specific
>   version has.

The newest development builds of Dolphin do in fact have the netplay functionality that dc-netplay 4.0-652 does. As far as I know most netplay communities have since abandoned dc-netplay 4.0-652 as it is now considered obsolete.

If you still want to want to use it an option is to compile it from source.